# R scatter plot two groups one regression line

Tags: r

In ggplot2 I am trying to make a scatter plot in Rstudio using a grouping variable (for the different colours of the points), however I would like to have one regression line for the data as a whole.
Would be most grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example using the `iris` data set:

```
data(iris)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
      geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

The 'trick' is to specify the grouping variable in `geom_point` only, and not in the general aesthetics.

**Output:**

[image]